# Is my array index being shifted to the correct position to the right or left?

Tags: javascript

Is this code doing what I think that it is supposed to do. Does this shift the index i one position to the right.

```
       0011 would be come 0001 <-- because the sign bit is copied to the new position. I know that it is different than >>> which moves zeroes in the closest position.

       binarray[i>>2]
```

Code Here:

```
       str += hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8+4)) & 0xF) +
              hex_tab.charAt((binarray[i>>2] >> ((i%4)*8  )) & 0xF);
```

I have been looking at this all day and I just cannot see it any more!!!

More Code:

```
    lX8 = (lX & 0x80000000);
```

If I see something like the above that means that the & is comparing each bit in the two number or variables and in this case 0x8000000 in this case what is the value really of 0x8000000 in binary format.

```
     lResult = (lX & 0x3FFFFFFF) + (lY & 0x3FFFFFFF);
```

This code ass well adds the bits together but is 0x3FFFFFFF (what is this value translated to in binary?)

```
     h1 = bits >> 18 & 0x3f;
```

this from above would show that bits is shifted right by 18 & 0x3f which the 0x3f is HEX so and I would imagine that 18 is decimal.

Question: Is this all converted to binary and then used first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost. It actually shifts it two positions to the right, not one.

The number to the right of '>>' specifies how many bits to shift it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#%3E%3E_%28Sign-propagating_right_shift%29

Comment: Is the reason that it is shifting it two bits to the right because that is because that is how you get the next integer value. If I have 1010 and shift it 1 bit to the right it would be 0101 but if I shift it 2 bits then it would be 0010.

Comment: If i see some like this A >> 4 the number on the right is always the number of bits that is being shifted to the right. so in this case it would shift the value of a 4 bits to the right.